# How to delete all records from or empty a custom database table?

Tags: plugins, customization, database, wpdb

I can't seem to find a simple reliable way to do this - perhaps?:

```
// delete row ##
global $wpdb;
$delete = $wpdb->query( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
         "DELETE * FROM `wp_table_name`"
    )
);

// return ##
$return = __('Table Emptied.');
if ( $wpdb->last_error ) {
    $return = $wpdb->last_error;
}
```

But this gives me the classic:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM wp_table_name' at line 1

Comment: Not sure but shouldn't you use `$wpdb` instead of `$this`?

Comment: The SQL looks right if you have a table named `wp_table_name` which I doubt. There is also [`truncate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html). I don't see how this is a WordPress question though.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - thanks, the table_name is whitelisted.. I think using $wpdb makes this a WP question.. this is a WP plugin using a table in the WP DB.. I've added an answer below - thanks again!

Comment: But it isn't a `$wpdb` error. It is a just a SQL error.

Comment: isn't it true that all WordPress errors are PHP errors, by the same logic ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks @s_ha_dum - Truncate does the job nicely:

```
// delete row ##
global $wpdb;
$delete = $wpdb->query("TRUNCATE TABLE `wp_table_name`");
```

Answer (score 15):

I would just modify Q Studio example to:

```
global $wpdb;
$table  = $wpdb->prefix . 'table_name';
$delete = $wpdb->query("TRUNCATE TABLE $table");
```

Answer (score 3):

2 years late, but maybe this will help someone in the future :)

The correct syntax for deleting rows from a MySQL table is:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_table_name`
WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is late and the answer been accepted. But no one mentioned that your `DELETE` SQL statement is incorrect. Try this:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_table_name`
```

However, this might still not work. You might need to change your MariaDB/MySQL settings, which protects such deletes, to prevent you from mistakenly deleting a full set of data. To make it work, you have to

```
DELETE FROM `wp_table_name` WHERE `some_column` = 'some_value'
```

Cheers